Moving from PowerBI PPU to PowerBI Embed license for PowerBi Embed in Angular project
We are going to build a PowerBI + Angular embed solution. Target audience is all the users in my organization.
Architecture overview (using embed license with production in mind)

We will create App registration for MSAL authentication for the angular app. We will also add PowerBI specific API Permission
PowerBI developers will enable service principal access and above service principal
In .Net we will add REST API to generate embed token
In Angular we will first call the embed token generation API, then we will use groupId and reportId to embed the report using powerbi-client-angular package.

Keeping in mind the upfront cost, we will start with PPU license for the development, QA, UAT phase. But, before production deployment how much changes will be required besides upgrading the license from PPU to Embed? The estimated development period is 3 months.
Decision to start with embed vs upgrade to embed is dependent on upfront cost and additional changes just before production. Need some much needed insight.
FYI Wallace Breza
